# syncWithoutDetaching throws integrity constraint violation error, but sync does not when passing detached param to false

Tags: php, laravel

We are using syncWithoutDetaching with a table called strategy_department which has a unique constraint on a primary key with strategy_id and department_id having to be unique.

Laravel allows us to pass a single arg like an id (i.e. 1001), however the docs don't list that as an option https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_syncWithoutDetaching. There are no errors thrown.

However we see an on and off integrity constraint when using it this way. Is there an error with syncWithDetaching with a single id passed as an arg that doesn't allows work?

Sample code

```
$strategy_package->strategy()->first()->departments()->syncWithoutDetaching($task->service->department->id);
```

We are triggering a graphql endpoint with this code with several different requests (that could have the same department id).

Is there an issue running this call in parallel?

```
$strategy_package->strategy()->first()->departments()->sync($task->service->department->id, false);
```

appears to be working correctly, not sure why one would produce a result that the other would not

We are using V8 of Laravel

Comment: the problem has to be somewhere else as the sync(..,false) and syncWithoutDetaching() are the same as you showed

Comment: @suxgri when switching to use sync it works properly though

Comment: does one always succeed and the other always fail? if so they may be different (for some reason that i don t know), but if the syncWithoutDetaching sometimes is ok and other times fail i would test more, also what is the integrity error?

Comment: it's an integrity constraint for a duplicate insert into the an intermediate table.

sync always works, syncWithoutDetached does not work sometimes

Comment: i tried myself with various combinations and i never had any errors, the idea is that laravel will recognize the new insert that have to be made and stops duplicate inserts before making the query. If something is not working in your case you can log the $changes variable (after the array merge) and see if something is wrong (meaning you should see duplicates there in the log when you get the duplicate error)

Comment: that's what i thought but it still throws the error. we are triggering multiple async requests that all syncWithoutDetach, so we were wondering if this method fails with multiple inserts at the same time

Comment: what i meant is that this need further debugging (by logging from the sync method in the vendor) from you. i tried multiple syncWDetach and sync(..,false) with various id combination (all in the same request) and it never failed because eloquent recognize the new insert that have to be made and discard the duplicates that would lead to the integrity constraint at the db level. in your case eloquent seem to fail to recognize the duplicates so duplicate insert is tried in sql -> sql throw the error (because the strategy_id and department_id that forms the primary id can t be repeated.